# I could really use some help getting my Instagram app approved

Tags: wordpress, plugins, instagram, instagram-api

I have been attempting to setup a website for my company that has a DTG (Direct To Garment) printer, so that eventually after the site is completely set up, people will have the ability pull images from their Instagram account (as well as Facebook), to have printed with us.

The site, [www.fanemb.com/lumise](http://www.fanemb.com/lumise) (right now it's in a subdomain, eventually it will have a completely different domain name), is developed in WordPress and utilizes a plugin, Lumise, to offer a page that has a design stage, with different shirts/hoodies, that people can design their own apparel on.

Long story short, I've been able to get a Facebook app approved, with the user_photos permission. I cannot seem to get the Instagram app approved. Whenever I submit it for approval it get's kicked back. In the Lumise plugin settings, an area to enter my Facebook APP ID, which I've done, and that gives me no problems. There's another space labled Instagram API. I put in my Instagram APP ID there, even though I'm assuming that's not what it's looking for. If I just leave that area blank, then the Facebook for Developers review team can't see any Instagram Login button...so it get's kicked back. If put the Instagram App ID in there, the login button appears...but after going through all the steps to log in through the authorization window that generates, I get a message like this:

{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid response type: token"}

So then it get's kicked back for that reason. Basically, I'm just completely confused. I don't know how to fix this.

I've  been told by the Facebook For Developers reviewers that all I need is Instagram Basic Display.

Comment: Why are you even trying to submit your app, before you got the functionality working properly?

Comment: _"but after going through all the steps to log in through the authorization window that generates, I get a message like this:"_ - sounds like an issue with the plugin itself (I am assuming, you did not actively specify a response type yourself anywhere in the settings?) Then you should contact the plugin provider for support.

Comment: I have had a hunch for months that this is an issue with the plugin itself, thanks for confirming my suspicions. Trying to get help from them on this isssue is like pulling teeth...the plugin doesn't really give a good explanation at all on how to set this feature up correctly, I mean they have to know that the average person using it isn't all that familiar with what to do, they are just hoping the plugin will do it for them. Check this out (their explanation video): https://youtu.be/g7myV9scnCE

Comment: the above link addresses the Facebook/Instagram functionality around 00:47....so they give people an option to buy a extension to the base plugin, but don't really explain it that well. And as far as actively specifing a response type....you can see in that video that they make no reference to people doing anything other than just entering in a Facebook app ID and Instagram API and toggling a switch...lol...so yeah, I think you're correct in your assumption that it's a problem with the plugin, most of the plugin users aren't web developers, they're people trying to run a business.